# how to add (href) in (a) by jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to add (URL) this in HTML(a)

```
var gm = document.body.innerHTML.match(/id=\d+.+على.+id=\d+/g);


for(var i=0;i<10;++i) 
window.open('/game.php?village=' + gm[i].match(/id=(\d+)/g)[0].replace("id=",'') + '&screen=place&target=' + gm[i].match(/id=(\d+)/g)[1].replace("id=",''));
```

HTML

```
<b id='ABC'>
<a id='f' href ='' >ABC1</a>
<a id='f' href ='' >ABC2</a>
<a id='f' href ='' >ABC3</a>
<a id='f' href ='' >ABC4</a>
<a id='f' href ='' >ABC5</a>
</b>
```

but i do not want use : => window.open

i want use (var) like this :

```
var ss = '/game.php?village=' + gm[i].match(/id=(\d+)/g)[0].replace("id=",'') + '&screen=place&target=' + gm[i].match(/id=(\d+)/g)[1].replace("id=",'');
```

In order to add her (href)

by jquery or javascript

```
<b id='ABC'>
<a id='f' href ='' >ABC1</a>
<a id='f' href ='' >ABC2</a>
<a id='f' href ='' >ABC3</a>
<a id='f' href ='' >ABC4</a>
<a id='f' href ='' >ABC5</a>
</b>
```

i use this

```
$("#abc ").each(function(){
$(this).find("a").attr("href",ss);

});
```

but Error ?

how ?
and thanks

Comment: ID must be unique . Use class Instead for multiple usage .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `$("#abc ").each()` iterates over element having `id` `abc`: iterating over an `id` selector is pointless since `id` should be unique in a document. You should iterate over the `<a>` elements instead
- Selectors are case sensitive. `id` in your HTML is `ABC` and in your
  selector you're using `abc`. You should use the correct id.

  ```
  $("#ABC a").each(function () {
    $(this).attr("href", ss);
  });
  ```

*side notes:*

- Multiple elements should not have the same `id`: you should use a
  class instead...
- jQuery setter methods generally iterates over the collection upon which they are called, so unless you have to perform multiple operations, no need to manually iterate. `$("#ABC a").attr("href", ss);` will do the same.

Answer (score -1):

```
$("#abc a").each(function(){
$(this).attr("href",ss);
});
```

You have to iterate anchor tag/.

Answer (score -1):

There are 2 ways to do this.

#### By class name:

Change your anchor tag ID to CLASS, like this:

```
...
<a class='f' href ='' >ABC1</a>
...
```

Change jQuery code to:

```
$(".f ").attr("href",ss);
```

#### By child/parent:

```
$("#abc").find('a').attr("href",ss);
```

NOTE: DOM element IDs should be unique. No two elements should have the same ID. You can assign the same class to multiple elements.